# Поиск по таблице с ключевыми словами

Tags: php, mysql, поиск

Есть таблица. [image: таблица]

Запрос: красивый красный 
На выходе мы должны получить catalog_id:
1 - (полное соответствие), 4 - (красный)

Т.е суть в том, что сперва мы должны выбрать из таблицы все соответствия ключевых слов, потом мы получаем там где совпадает допустим 2 ключевых слова, а потом где одно.

Запрос может состоять из 10 ключевых, данных в таблице много, но как сделать релеватность в данном случае я никак не пойму.

Сумбурно написал, но суть в том: на входе n кол-во ключевых слов. Нужно сперва отобразить все найденные, потом в порядке убывания по кол-ву совпадений.

Comment: Напишите, какой результат Вы ожидаете для `красивый красный`?

Comment: 1,4 - результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то должно работать так

```sql
SELECT
  catalog_id,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  keyword IN ('красивый', 'красный')
GROUP BY
  catalog_id
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
```